# adding value to only a single column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and i need to add data only to a specific column

DF

```
A  B  C
1  2  3
2  3  4
a  d  f
22 3  3
```

output :

```
A  B  C
1  2  3
2  3  4
a  d  f
22 3  3
32
      34
```

I tried : `df['A'].append(pd.DataFrame([valuetoadd]), ignore_index=True)` where `valuetoadd` is a variable

Comment: What value do you want to add and to which column? Please share the expected output and sample input.

Comment: Edited... please check

Comment: You want to add `32` to column 'A' and `34` to Column 'C'?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) with a dictionary (or list of dictionaries, one per row):

```
>> df.append({'A':32}, ignore_index=True)

    A    B    C
0   1    2    3
1   2    3    4
2   a    d    f
3  22    3    3
4  32  NaN  NaN


>> df.append([{'A':32}, {'C':34}], ignore_index=True)

     A    B    C
0    1    2    3
1    2    3    4
2    a    d    f
3   22    3    3
4   32  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  NaN   34
```

Comment: It is not adding

Comment: Instead of 32 I need value from a a variable to beadded

Comment: I am trying to add into empty dataframe

Comment: You can put whatever value you want in the dictionary and it will be added in the next row for that column

Comment: Give an example of what you are trying to do

Comment: After checking both answers, I realized you will need to have df=df.append({'A':32}, ignore_index=True), so that you can have your df assigned the appended version.

Comment: unfortunately it is deprecated now

Answer (score 7):

You can use pandas.DataFrame.append with a dictionary (or list of dictionaries, one per row):

```
df=df.append({'a':variable1}, ignore_index=True)
df=df.append({'a':variable1,'b':variable2}, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

As `.append` is deprecated [now](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.4/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#whatsnew-140-deprecations-frame-series-append), another solution using `pd.concat` would be:

```py
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({"A":[32]})], ignore_index=True)
```

I'd prefer the old syntax, though.