# How to (elegantly) add single values and rows to a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine the following DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

animal_sizes = pd.DataFrame({"Animal": ["Horse", "Mouse"], 
                             "Size": ["Large", "Small"]})
```

| Animal | Size |
| --- | --- |
| Horse | Large |
| Mouse | Small |

I want to add another row for "Dog". If I understand correctly, I have to first create another DataFrame and then concatenate the new and the existing DataFrame.

```
pd.concat([animal_sizes, 
           pd.DataFrame({"Animal": ["Dog"],
                         "Size": ["Medium"]})]
         )
```

| Animal | Size |
| --- | --- |
| Horse | Large |
| Mouse | Small |
| Dog | Medium |

This doesn't seem terribly elegant. Is there a simpler way? I imagine something like `animal_sizes.append_row(["Dog", "Medium"])`.

Imagine I only want to add another value to the Animal column. (Perhaps I haven't measured the size yet.) Again, `pd.concat` with an explicit empty (or NaN) value for the Size column seems awkward:

```
pd.concat([animal_sizes, 
           pd.DataFrame({"Animal": ["Crow"], "Size": [""]})]
```

| Animal | Size |
| --- | --- |
| Horse | Large |
| Mouse | Small |
| Crow |  |

Is there a simpler solution? I'm looking for something like `animal_sizes["Animal"].append_value("Crow")`.

I know about [`pd.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) (see [this fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53318210/5817683)), but not only is it deprecated, it also expects you to explicate the column for each new row value. This makes it slightly unwieldy for my taste.

```
animal_sizes.append({"Animal": "Crow"}, ignore_index=True)
```

**Are there more elegant solutions for this very simple problem?**

Answer (score 4):

I recommend defining an appropriate index (animals in this case) and using it to insert new rows *by name*. Use dictionaries to add incomplete rows.

```
import pandas as pd

animal_sizes = pd.DataFrame({"Animal": ["Horse", "Mouse"], 
                             "Size": ["Large", "Small"],
                             "othercol": ["A", "B"]}
                           ).set_index("Animal")

animal_sizes.loc["Dog"] = {"othercol": "C"}
animal_sizes.loc["Elephant"] = ["verylarge", "D"]
animal_sizes.loc["unspecifiedanimal"] = {}

print(animal_sizes)

# result:
                        Size othercol
Animal                               
Horse                  Large        A
Mouse                  Small        B
Dog                      NaN        C
Elephant           verylarge        D
unspecifiedanimal        NaN      NaN
```

Adding an existing animal replaces a row. This may or may not be intended behavior. If the goal is to blindly dump rows into the table while accepting duplicates, the best solution might still be `concat`.

Comment: Problem of solution is if exist `Mouse` it not insert, but overwrite.

Comment: I think `animal_sizes.loc["Mouse"] = {"othercol": "C"}`

Comment: So *that's* what named indices are for!

Comment: @henning Among other things. Have a look at the pandas docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html

Answer (score 2):

Solution for default `RangeIndex` values in index for always inserting new rows to end of `DataFrame`:

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with list, only necessary same length like number of columns - new index value is created by length of rows:

```
animal_sizes.loc[len(animal_sizes)] = ["Dog", "Medium"]
print (animal_sizes)
  Animal    Size
0  Horse   Large
1  Mouse   Small
2    Dog  Medium
```

If need also specify columns names:

```
animal_sizes.loc[len(animal_sizes)] = {"Animal": "Dog", "Size": "Medium"}
print (animal_sizes)
  Animal    Size
0  Horse   Large
1  Mouse   Small
2    Dog  Medium
```

Comment: This may overwrite existing rows in the general case where the df index is not strictly `range(len(animal_sizes))`.

Comment: @mcsoini - added to answer `Solution for default RangeIndex value`